# Find a bound such that a measurable function is p-integrable

Tags: real-analysis, probability, lp-spaces

A measurable function is said to be in $L^p$ space $\mathscr{L}^p(\mathscr{X}, \mathscr{A}, \mu, \mathbb{R})$ if $\int \lvert f \rvert^p d\mu < \infty$. And a measurable function has power decaying rate of $q \geq 1$ if $\limsup_{t \to \infty} t^q  \mu(\{x: |f| >t\}) < \infty$, I need to find a best function $M$ such that whenever $f$ has power decaying rate of $q$, then it still $p$-integrable if $p < M(q)$. How to find this best function?

What I have tried, I have tried to rewrite $\int \lvert f \rvert^p d\mu = \int_0^{\infty} p t^{p-1}\mu(\{x: \lvert f(x) \rvert > t\})dt $(We can get this by using product measure.) So I at least get some similar expressions. But I don't know what to do next.

A best function means if I replace the function $M$ with another function $M' < M$, then this statement won't holds.

Possibly related concept: weak $L^p$ space.

Question solved.

Comment: what is a "best function"?

Comment: @Masacroso Sorry, I edited

Comment: $t^p\mu(|f|>t)\leq \int_{\{|f|>t\}}|f|^p\,d\mu\xrightarrow{t\rightarrow\infty}0$

Comment: @OliverDíaz What do you mean by this? First of all, if this is Markov inequality, it's stated incorrectly. Secondly, you seemed you didn't understand my question.

Comment: @Beginner: The inequality is indeed Markov's inequality. If $\limsup_{t\rightarrow\infty}t^p\mu(|f|>t)>0$, then $f$ can't be $L_p$-integrable. That probably all you can say.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Sorry. But why there is a $\{\lvert f \rvert > t\}$ under the $\int$ sign? In a standard form, I haven't seen it before.

Comment: $\{|f|>t\}$ is short notation for $\{x\in\Omega: |f(x)|>t\}$.

Comment: @OliverDíaz It's an  incorrect formula.

Comment: Which "formula" is incorrect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139755/discussion-between-beginner-and-oliver-diaz).